# How to force a IE version in a Winform WebControl?

Tags: .net, winforms, .net-3.5, web-controls

I was trying to find out the problem in one web design I had and remembered to use a simple javascript to get the browser version as I had completly 2 different behaviors

so I add this:

```
<div id="example"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

txt = "<p>Browser CodeName: " + navigator.appCodeName + "</p>";
txt+= "<p>Browser Name: " + navigator.appName + "</p>";
txt+= "<p>Browser Version: " + navigator.appVersion + "</p>";
txt+= "<p>Cookies Enabled: " + navigator.cookieEnabled + "</p>";
txt+= "<p>Platform: " + navigator.platform + "</p>";
txt+= "<p>User-agent header: " + navigator.userAgent + "</p>";

document.getElementById("example").innerHTML=txt;

</script>
```

and found out this:

[image]

[original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cijur.png)

even though I have **Internet Explorer 8** installed on this machine, the webbrowser control loads a version of IE (Internet Explorer 7) that is not the one installed.

> How can I **force** using the correct version?

Comment: Looks like it loaded it in compatibility mode to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually it is possible to force the control to use particular version of IE. Have a look at this article: [Witch version of browser is used by the WebBrowser control?](http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2011/06/06/witch-version-of-browser-is-used-by-the-webbrowser-control/)

Comment: great catch ... I hope not to find problems with the proxy as many companies use it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to do that. One option is to embed WebKit into your app:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/webkitdotnet/

This will make your install a lot bigger, but at least you'll have embedded a competent browser. :)

Comment: nice link :) will give that a try