# Winform webbrowser reCAPTCHA doesn't show

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

I create a Winform application, when i use webbrowser.

My problem, when i navigate to the site, the reCAPTCHA doesn't show. I got an error message my webbrowser doesn't support, i should update.

If i know right, the winform webbrowser work from IE what we have got in our computer.

My computer has got IE 11. I tried check this website with my IE, and ther the reCAPTCHA working perfectly.

How can i solved this problem? I want show the reCAPTCHA in my build in webbrowser in my winform.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to force a IE version in a Winform WebControl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4931667/how-to-force-a-ie-version-in-a-winform-webcontrol)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The version of the WebBrowser is the problem:

The only thing that you need to do is to set the version of the browser in the key registry:

Something like this will do the job:

```
var appName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName);
                Microsoft.Win32.Registry.SetValue(@"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION",
                      appName, 11000, Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind.DWord);

    //where: 11000 is currently the last version of iExplorer
```

Please note that 11000 is the value that worked(for me). If you use 10000 or lower it is not going to work.

Comment: Alternatively, you can just get your app's process name, in my case appName.vshost.exe, then go make the registry key yourself.

Comment: Cool solution! Thanks

Comment: You saved my life my friend!